# Как добавить единицы измерения для EditText?

Tags: android

Есть EditText с inputType="numberDecimal". Мне нужно ограничить его значением 999. Всего можно ввести 3 символа без точки и 4 символа с точкой. При вводе цифры добавлять единицы измерения литры/тонны итд. Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала можно добавить ограничение по величине. Делаем [фильтр](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android):

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
        try {
            int input = Interger.parseInt(dest.subSequence(0, dstart)+source.toString()+dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length()));
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

и дальше прикрепляем его к полю ввода:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", "12")});
```

[вот есть документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter) по данному вопросу. Дальше мы добавляем слушатель ввода:

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      
   }
  });
```

где в методе `afterTextChanged` добавляем ваши единицы измерения. Так же можно по логике обойтись и без фильтрации ввода, просто добавив обработку введенного текста в `onTextChanged` методе. Там можно получать из строки int проверять его на предмет соответствия и если все ок, то добавлять единицу измерения.

Comment: Использую аналогичный фильтр, но если его установить, то уже нельзя добавить текст методом setText(). W/System.err: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test string". Исключение выбрасывается в методе filter. А это значит что из слушателя текст не изменить.

Comment: Неверно вычисляете input. Должно быть так:
`int input = Interger.parseInt(dest.subSequence(0, dstart)+source.toString()+dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length()));`
Иначе вставка в середину строки будет неверно обработана.

Comment: хм... тупанул немного) спс) сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько путей:

- поставить на поле EditText слушатель TextWatcher, который будет отслеживать изменение текста. и в onTextChanged отслеживать изменения и исправлять значения, вводимые пользователем (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher)
- создать маску для EditText (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912375/masked-input-using-edittext-widget-in-android)
- никак не ограничивать значение EditText, но после ввода проверять полученное значение и выводить рядом ошибку "Максимальное значение - 999"